# Send textbox values from buttonclick outside form in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where I got my Ajax.BeginForm and it submits as it should. But then I have a "save icon" and when I press that button I need the values from inside the form. The form submits presents a calculation and the save icon is suppose to save it all.

But when I press the save icon (with Url.Action("SaveExcel", "Save") I can't get the values from the textboxes. How do I do that?

My HTML:

```
        <a href="@Url.Action("SaveExcel", "Save")" title="Save"><img src="../../Images/glyphicons_446_floppy_save.png" alt="save" id="saveIcon"></a>

<!-- Contains forms and input for annuity calculation -->
<div class="calcInput" id="calcInput">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowDetailAnnuity", "Calculation", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "CalcDetail",
    LoadingElementId = "Loader",
}))
{
   <div class="calculateBox">
        <label for="calcOption">Choose value to calculate:</label>
        <select id="calcOption" name="calcOption" title="Choose what value you want to calculate">
            <option value="PMT" id="PMT" name="PMT">Payment (PMT)</option>
            <option value="I" id="I" name="I">Interest (I)</option>
            <option value="FV" id="FV" name="FV">Future value (FV)</option>
            <option value="PV" id="PV" name="PV">Present value (PV)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="calculateBox" background-color="#777777">
        @Html.Label("Present value (PV)", new { @id = "pvLabel" })
        @Html.TextBox("PresentValue", null, new { @class = "PresentValue" })
        @Html.Label("Future value (FV)", new { @id = "fvLabel" })
        @Html.TextBox("FutureValue", null, new { @class = "FutureValue" })
        @Html.Label("Interest rate", new { @id = "intRateLabel" })
        @Html.TextBox("InterestRate", null, new { @class = "InterestRate" }) <br /> <br />
        <input type="radio" name="advanceOrArrears" id="inAdvance" value="inAdvance" /> In advance<br />
        <input type="radio" name="advanceOrArrears" id="inArrears" value="inArrears" /> In arrears
    </div>
    <div class="calculateBox">
        <label for="startDate">Start date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="StartDate" name="startdate" title="Choose start date for your calculation" /><br />
        @Html.Label("Payment frequency")
        <select id="PmtFreq" name="PmtFreq" title="Choose the payment frequency, for example: Every month">
            <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
            <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
        </select><br /><br />
        @Html.Label("No of payment periods")
        @Html.TextBox("PaymentPeriods")
        @Html.Label("Date time convention")
        <select id="DTC" name="DTC" title="Choose your Date time convention">
            <option value="360/360">360/360</option>
            <option value="365/365">365/365</option>
        </select><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" id="CalcBtn" class="calcBtn" name="SubmitBtn" value="Calculate" title="Calculate your calculation" />
    </div>
}
</div>
```

My controller:

```
public class SaveController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SaveExcel(string PresentValue) //Can't get PresentValue here..
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

I have tried using the names of the textboxes as parameter in the controller, and I have also tried Request.Form["PresentValue"] but nothing of that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need two submit buttons.

Try turning your save button into a submit button inside your form, so that you have:

```
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Calculate"/>
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Save"/>
```

And then in your controller, differentiate between which button was pressed by having something like:

```
public ActionResult SaveExcel(string PresentValue, string SubmitButton) 
{

    if(SubmitButton == "Save") .... <save code>
    if(SubmitButton == "Calculate") .... <calc code>

    return View();
}
```